# How to get onto a duct in Batman Arkham Asylum from the flooded corridor

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

[image: Image of the duct I'm trying to get onto]

I'm in the flooded corridor, and I've no idea how to get onto that duct. I'm playing it on PC.

**EDIT**

To get a better picture at where I am, please follow [this link](http://www.gamespot.com/features/6216207/p-23.html). That page contains the following paragraph:

> The Abandoned Chamber can be confused,
>   so follow these directions: From the
>   entrance, head left, jump the gap,
>   then proceed down the staircase (into
>   the central structure), then up
>   another set. Jump the gap and proceed
>   through the door. Climb the ledges
>   within, then **grapple into the vent
>   overhead**.

I'm in the exact position (in the picture above) where I'm supposed to "grapple into the vent overhead." But that vent can't be grappled! And it is too high to be climbed. That's why I'm stuck.

Comment: It would help if you give a little more information about where you are, that image doesn't have any distinct feature. Also, I'm assuming just using the grappling hook didn't help?

Comment: yea, looks like something you can just grappling up to

Comment: @Oak, @yx01: please see my edit.

Comment: This only occurs in pirated versions of the game (OP confirmed he is using pirate version in accepted answer comments)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is about a bug that only appears in illegal copies of the game.

Comment: Meta Discussion: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11275/what-should-we-do-about-piracy-specific-bug-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This video shows how to grapple up to that vent](http://www.ign.com/videos/2010/03/03/batman-arkham-asylum-ps3-baa-killing-the-power).  (Jump to the 4'20" mark to avoid seeing a couple Riddler challenge solutions.)  Sometimes Batman's grapple gun can be kind of finicky, so try a bunch of different spots.

If that doesn't work, make sure you're using a legal copy of the game.  According to [this thread on Eidos' forums](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=95030), it looks like the designers created intentional glitches in the game to combat piracy. These glitches go away when the game is licensed.

Comment: thanks for the video. it shows to grapple on the ledge. but the game doesn't allow me to grapple there. i'm playing on PC and that video was probably for PS3. why does they behave differently?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried standing in a bunch of different place. Sometimes you have to be in a very specific spot for the grapple to work.

Comment: @splattered bits: couldn't find such place. :(

Comment: @Donotalo Hmmm. Could be a bug/glitch. Does the PC version let you download any updates or patches?

Comment: @Donotalo [This Gamespot thread](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/action/batmanarkhamasylum/answers.html?qid=111759) suggests that it may be a "feature" in pirated copies of the game.

Comment: @splattered bits: hmm. unfortunately i live in a country where original games are never found. :(