# Can't climb on dumpster to get to the ladder in the first mission

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I cannot climb on the dumpster to get to the ladder in the first part of the game as Bruce Wayne. I have tried everything to no avail. Is the game bugged?

Comment: Did you try turning it off then on again?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of it? That would probably help.

Comment: Does it crash or does it not allow you to?

Comment: Do you have a legal, licensed copy of the game? I know Batman: Arkham Asylym [has an intentional glitch in unlicensed copies that prevents you from progressing](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/15991/2341).